# Left Join and apply case logic on Pyspark Dataframes

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am learning to code PySpark. I am able join two dataframes by building SQL like `views` on top them using `.createOrReplaceTempView()` and get the output I want. However I want to learn how to do the same by operating directly on the dataframe instead of creating `views`.

This is my code

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView('left_table')
df2.createOrReplaceTempView('right_table')

    spark.sql('''
    select
    l.*,
    CASE WHEN r.id IS NULL THEN current_timestamp() ELSE r.timestamp END ts,
    from
    left_table l 
    left join 
    right_table r
    on l.id = r.id 
    ''').show()
```

For **matching** `id` I want the `timestamp` column to be taken from the right table. For `id` that is **available only in left table** I want to use system timestamp using `current_timestamp()` for the final column value.

How do i achieve this by operating directly on dataframes `df1` and `df2` instead of building views?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a left join and then coalesce the NULL timestamps with the current timestamp:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1.join(df2, 'id', 'left') \
   .drop(*[col for col in df2.columns if col != 'timestamp']) \
   .withColumn('timestamp', F.coalesce(F.col('timestamp'), F.current_timestamp()))
```